# Get all recently changed documents in a CouchDB database

Tags: node.js, couchdb, cradle

Using following code:

```js
db.changes({'include_docs':true}).on('response', function (res) {
    res.on('data', function (change) {
        console.log(change);
    });
});
```

I am able to get all (old & new) documents that are changed in the database but how can I get documents that have changed recently?

Comment: is this requirement for replication ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the `since` parameter, details in [the changes docs](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_database_API#Changes)